# PDO Select Multiples count()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

Here is what i like to say in MYSQL_QUERY

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM msg WHERE view = 0 AND nd = 'test' AND type = 0) as inbox,
   (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM msg WHERE view = 0 AND nd = 'test' AND type = 1) as sent,
   (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM msg WHERE view = 0 AND nd = 'test' AND type = 2) as draft,
   (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM msg WHERE view = 0 AND nd = 'test' AND type = 3) as spam,
   (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM msg WHERE view = 0 AND nd = 'test' AND type = 4) as trash";
```

I like to go with PDO, i tryed this, but i got an error:

```
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as inbox FROM msg WHERE view = :view AND nd = :nd AND type = :type),
(SELECT COUNT(*) as sent FROM msg WHERE view = :view AND nd = :nd AND type = :type),
(SELECT COUNT(*) as draft FROM msg WHERE view = :view AND nd = :nd AND type = :type),
(SELECT COUNT(*) as trash FROM msg WHERE view = :view AND nd = :nd AND type = :type)
");
$query->execute(array(
':view' => 0,
':nd' => 'test',
':type' => 1
    ));
$pageRow=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$inbox = $pageRow[0];
$sent = $pageRow[1];
$draft = $pageRow[2];
$trash = $pageRow[3];
```

Comment: What might be the error you are getting ... hmm.. let me think, what it might be ... out of all the errors that exist.

Comment: You can only use named parameters once, not four times each.

Comment: Even if you could reuse named parameters, how did you expect to get all the different types when all your subqueries use the same `:type`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(type = 0), 0) as inbox,
       IFNULL(SUM(type = 1), 0) as sent,
       IFNULL(SUM(type = 2), 0) as draft,
       IFNULL(SUM(type = 3), 0) as spam,
       IFNULL(SUM(type = 4), 0) as trash
FROM msg
WHERE view = :view AND nd = :nd
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, sounds cool, i don't see the error, but how can i print the affected rows ?

Comment: echo $pageRow[0]; ? it's empty

Comment: Can you run the query by hand, either from the `mysql` command line tool or phpmyadmin?

Comment: I guess Simon's comment about errors didn't induce you to add error reporting to your script.